# How to deal with overwhelming presence (or absence) of particular values on a sliding scale?

Tags: bayesian, model, zero-inflation

I have data from a sliding scale with values from 0 to 100 (not my choice of instrument, but it's what I have). The scale has a default value of 50. Participants respond on the scale before (pre) and after (post) doing an exercise.

I have a couple problems to address.

(1) There turns out to be a massive effect of default bias so that many participants are leaving the scale at the value of 50.

(2) The values 0, 25, 75, 100 are also strongly preferred. Multiples of 5 are preferred to a lesser degree. (See histogram below)

I am trying to predict the "post" rating based on the "pre" rating and two additional continuous predictors. How can I account for these idiosyncrasies in my modeling? My first instinct is to remove values of 50 altogether because I cannot trust that the participant was even engaging with the scale in any genuine manner. They may have just intended to skip the rating segment in order to get to the exercise segment or to finish their engagement with the study. This is a real-world dataset not collected in a lab so there was no control over how people interacted with the instruments. Even if I take that less than ideal approach, I'm still left with the issue of how to deal with the fact the people are drawn to 0, 25, 75, 100 and to a lesser degree--multiples of 5. Omitting cases with a rating of 50 also leaves me with a problem of having to account for a missing chunk of the distribution when I build my model. This is additionally problematic because that missing chunk is exactly where a linear regression model or a bayesian model with a normal prior expects the distribution to have the most mass.

One idea is to use something like this [bayesian zero one inflated beta regression](https://vuorre.netlify.com/post/2019/02/18/analyze-analog-scale-ratings-with-zero-one-inflated-beta-models/#zoib-regression). Is there a way I can adapt this to also estimate inflated occurrences for "25" and "75"?

I'm also very open to suggestions completely different from anything I have mentioned.

[image: histogram of data]

Answer (score 1):

An imperfect solution, but: you could split it into 5 groups: at 0, at 50, at 100, 1 through 49, and 51 through 99. Even though it's a continuous scale, it looks like many respondents are making categorical decisions, and that would capture that. Then you could model that as a dependent variable using ordinal regression.

If you are using something like Stan, writing the model in Stan itself instead of using a port of it from Python or R, you could divide all of the values by 100 to get it in the unit interval. Then you could adapt the zero-one inflated likelihood to also include 50.

Comment: Ah hah, I found out that the brms package in R which is what I use also offers the ability to create a "custom_family()" so that I can define my own distribution. I will explore this further